# Langchain: Embedding memory into an agent

Tags: langchain

I'm trying to make my STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent to have memory, so when I ask about a specific email and want further details on it it knows I'm talking about our previous conversation. I'm using GmailToolkit from Langchain:

```
toolkit = GmailToolkit() 
tools = toolkit.get_tools()

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory()

agent = initialize_agent(
    tools=toolkit.get_tools(),
    llm=llm,
    agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, input_varaib, memory=memory
),
```

When I ask about an email for the first time from a specific sender it does this:

> Entering new  chain...
> Action:

```
{
  "action": "search_gmail",
  "action_input": {
    "query": "from:Anna Davis",
    "resource": "messages",
    "max_results": 1
  }
}
```

Observation: [{'id': '18930ed97d039fc1', 'threadId': '18930ed97d039fc1', 'snippet': 'Hello, CONGRATULATIONS! You won a 6-month free subscription with Gymglish in our Citizen Remote giveaway! To claim your prize, simply click on the email that we just sent you, and begin your new', 'body': '[, ]', 'subject': "You're a winner! Start your new language adventure with Gymglish\r\n today... =?UTF-8?Q?=F0=9F=98=8E?=", 'sender': 'Anna}]
Thought: I have the information I need
Action:

```
{
  "action": "Final Answer",
  "action_input": "The last email from Anna was about a 6-month free subscription with Gymglish in their Citizen Remote giveaway."
}
```

> Finished chain.
> The last email from Anna was about a 6-month free subscription with Gymglish in their Citizen Remote giveaway.

But when I ask a follow-up question like the specific subject of that email it get completely lost:

> Entering new  chain...
> Action:

```
{
  "action": "search_gmail",
  "action_input": {
    "query": "subject:<subject>"
  }
}
```

Observation: [{'id': '1878a27a9b20f4dd', 'threadId': '1878a27a9b20f4dd', 'snippet': 'Para una versión en línea de este mensaje, clic aquí. Hola Miguel Angel, ¡aprovecha esta promoción!! Síguenos en... Privacidad | Aviso Legal DEPORTES MARTÍ, SA DE CV (EMOCIÓN DEPORTIVA) COMO EMPRESA', 'body': '[, ]', 'subject': '=?utf-8?Q?Subject:*Miguel_Angel=F0=9F=9A=B4=E2=80=8D?=\r\n =?utf-8?Q?=E2=99=80=EF=B8=8F_Tenemos_una_promoci=C3=B3n_especial_para_ti*?=\r\n =?utf-8?Q?en_el_Cycling_Xperience_Sport_City_Ruta_Herencia_Otom=C3=AD!?=\r\n =?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=9A=B4=E2=80=8D=E2=99=80=EF=B8=8F_?=', 'sender': '"=?utf-8?Q?Emoci=C3=B3n_Deportiva?=" '}, {'id': '18631ed61f64ad01', 'threadId': '1862cb06aa4e60e4', 'snippet': '⚠️ Your email to jherring@rosen-group.com has not been opened yet. Snooze for 24H, 48H or 72H ( disable)', 'body': '\n\n\n\n\nReminder=\r\n\n\n\n\n\r\n        =E2=9A=\r\n=A0=EF=B8=8F\xa0Your email to jherring@rosen-group.com has not been opene=\r\nd yet.\xa0Snooze for\xa024H,\xa048H\xa0or\xa072H\xa0=\r\n;(disable)\r\n    =\r\n     \n\n\n\n', 'subject': 'Re: Subject: ROSEN Revisa de la Aplicacion - Respuesta Necesaria!', 'sender': 'Mailtrack Reminder reminders@mailtrack.io'}, {'id': '1862cc6c687af99d', 'threadId': '1862cb06aa4e60e4', 'snippet': 'Yes, that works for me. Thank you, El mar, 7 feb 2023 a la(s) 10:42, Jocelyn Herring (jherring@rosen-group.com) escribió: Hi Miguel, Are you available Friday 2/10 at 11:00am CST? If so, please confirm', 'body': '[, ]', 'subject': 'Re: Subject: ROSEN Revisa de la Aplicacion - Respuesta Necesaria!', 'sender': '=?UTF-8?B?TWlndWVsIMOBbmdlbCBIZXJuw6FuZGV6IE0u?= '}, {'id': '1862cc1f95eae8db', 'threadId': '1862cb06aa4e60e4', 'snippet': 'Hi Miguel, Are you available Friday 2/10 at
Thought: I have the subject of the email
Action:

```
{
  "action": "Final Answer",
  "action_input": "The subject of the email is 'Subject: ROSEN Revisa de la Aplicacion - Respuesta Necesaria!'"
}
```

> Finished chain.
> The subject of the email is 'Subject: ROSEN Revisa de la Aplicacion - Respuesta Necesaria!'

I expected it to have memory